# Is there a way to include partial using html-webpack-plugin?

Tags: html, webpack, frontend

I am using Webpack to compile my scripts and HTML (using `html-webpack-plugin`). The thing is, I have 5 HTML files that contains the same parts and I want to move these parts to separate `.html` files and then `include` these parts in every HTML file. This way, if I will change these smaller HTML files, it will recompile every HTML file to represent these changes.

Webpack does this for .js files by default, but can I use something like that for HTML files?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You can use `<%= require('html!./partial.html') %>` in your template. Example here: https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin/blob/master/examples/custom-template/template.html

Comment: How can you add template specific variables for each partial?

Comment: You can do string replacement on them `<% var template = require('html!./partial.html')%>` Next line is `<%=template.replace('${someVar}', someVar)%>` Pretty crude way to do it, but can't find a simpler solution right now.

Comment: You can try using - https://github.com/Vishal0203/file-include-webpack-plugin this works similar to `gulp-file-include`

Comment: what loader is required to be placed in webpack.config.js, in order for that to work?

Comment: Minor note on this - when using Webpack 4 you'll get an error: **BREAKING CHANGE: It's no longer allowed to omit the '-loader' suffix when using loaders.** - so the inline require needs to be `<%= require('html-loader!./partial.html') %>`

Comment: @klewis `npm install --save-dev html-loader` does the trick. Don't add the loader to the webpack config, otherwise it will interfere with `html-webpack-plugin`.

Comment: What about for .php partials?

Comment: Can you include a partial in a partial?

Answer (score 18):

Another slightly different solution.

Using `html-loader` with `interpolate` option.

https://github.com/webpack-contrib/html-loader#interpolation

```js
{ test: /\.(html)$/,
  include: path.join(__dirname, 'src/views'),
  use: {
    loader: 'html-loader',
    options: {
      interpolate: true
    }
  }
}
```

And then in html pages you can import partials html and javascript variables.

```html
<!-- Importing top <head> section -->
${require('./partials/top.html')}
<title>Home</title>
</head>
<body>
  <!-- Importing navbar -->
  ${require('./partials/nav.html')}
  <!-- Importing variable from javascript file -->
  <h1>${require('../js/html-variables.js').hello}</h1>
  <!-- Importing footer -->
  ${require('./partials/footer.html')}
</body>
```

`html-variables.js` looks like this:

```js
const hello = 'Hello!';
const bye = 'Bye!';

export {hello, bye}
```

The only downside is that you can't import other variables from `HtmlWebpackPlugin` like this `<%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.title %>` (at least I can't find a way to import them) but for me it's not an issue, just write the title in your html or use a separate javascript file for handle variables.

Comment: To follow up, i figured out how to import other variables from HtmlWebpackPlugin. Use the https://www.npmjs.com/package/ejs-html-loader and then you can use test: /\.html$/,
                use: [{
                    loader: 'ejs-html-loader',
                    options: {
                        htmlWebpackPlugin: htmlWebpackPlugin
                    }
                },
                {
                    loader: 'html-loader',
                    options: {
                        interpolate: true
                    }
                }]

Comment: `interpolate` was removed and the docs don't have an equivalent example: https://github.com/webpack-contrib/html-loader/blob/7aa1e4abe23426a9bd14a22fae632a695598bdba/CHANGELOG.md#100-2020-03-19

Answer (score 2):

Check out [Partials for HTML Webpack Plugin](https://github.com/colbyfayock/html-webpack-partials-plugin) for something a little more elegant. It lets you set up HTML files and include them similar to what you're looking for simply like:

```
plugins: [
  new HtmlWebpackPlugin(),
  new HtmlWebpackPartialsPlugin({
    path: './path/to/partials/body.html'
  })
]
```

Also configurable for where it gets added such as head vs body, opening vs closing, and lets you pass in variables.

Comment: that way you have to explicit specify any partial in the webpack config file, or i miss something? it's cumbersome when you akready include them in index.html... no?

Comment: the idea would be that you would no longer even have an index.html file and can avoid having a large single file that has to reference everything else which is a little more maintainable. it's also difficult (unless i haven't seen a good solution) to manage dynamic data from the index.html => inline loader partial flow, which this solves

Comment: it does'nt seems elegant at all to me. I feel more straightforward to have a single file wich act as layout template where you can set the position of every partial, in the way angular does with his component architecture. after this step, data content could be added as json\yaml file from wich partials read with a template engine as mustache\esj. This solution just paste partials togheter, it is'nt what asked for. (the "require" embedded in html seems more in the way the original asker needed)

Comment: what you're saying isn't what they are asking though, you're saying there's one index.html and that's not the case. they have multiple html files that they'd like to include each partial in, where the solution you're pushing would require them including that in each file. while that works, it requires maintaining each include in each file. additionally, they wouldn't have fun trying to do any local variable passing with that solution if it's a requirement. regardless, both solutions work and there's a little bit of personal preference in play here, the goal was to provide another option :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `html-loader` and `posthtml`. Then you can use the [`posthtml-include`](https://github.com/posthtml/posthtml-include) plugin.

```
const postHtml = require('posthtml');
const postHtmlInclude = require('posthtml-include');

{
  test: /\.html$/,
  use: {
    loader: 'html-loader',
    options: {
      esModule: false,
      preprocessor: async (content, loaderContext) => {
        try {
          return await postHtml(postHtmlInclude()).process(content)).html;
        } catch (error) {
          loaderContext.emitError(error);
          return content;
        }
      },
    },
  },
},
```