# Include HTML partials with Webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack, aframe

I'm creating a Webpack Boilerplate to easily create A-Frame projects. I configured Webpack to bundle JS and include the A-Frame library. Since A-Frame heavily relies on declarative HTML I would like to include entities as HTML snippets so I don't get a huge index.html file.

*So, I'm using HTML loader and trying to require / import other HTML files but they just show up as strings in the html.*

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kJAcP.png)

[Repository](https://github.com/samhoudmedia/aframe-boilerplate)

**How do I include HTML partials with html-loader? (or maybe another alternative)**

Comment: did you try using `<%= require('html-loader!./text.html') %>` like suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42193689/is-there-a-way-to-include-partial-using-html-webpack-plugin) ?

Comment: @PiotrAdamMilewski That post actually helped me, I needed to set the interpolate option in the webpack config. Thanks!

Maybe a bit unrelated and broad but do you know of any other possible solutions? Or common patterns how this is handled with A-Frame?

Comment: as for common patterns, you should check out [mixins](https://aframe.io/docs/0.8.0/core/mixins.html#sidebar) and ngoKevin's template [component](https://github.com/ngokevin/kframe/tree/master/components/template/)

Answer (score 4):

I use Nunjucks and run a watcher/builder in my Webpack.

```
var Nunjucks = require('nunjucks');
var webpack = require('webpack');

// Set up templating.
var nunjucks = Nunjucks.configure(path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'), {noCache: true});

// Initial Nunjucks render.
var html = nunjucks.render('index.html', getContext());

fs.writeFileSync('index.html', html);

// For development, watch HTML for changes to compile Nunjucks.
// The production Express server will handle Nunjucks by itself.
if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
  fs.watch('src', {recursive: true}, (eventType, filename) => {        
    if (filename.indexOf('.html') === -1) {
      return;
    }
    console.log(`${filename} updated.`);
    try {
      fs.writeFileSync('index.html', nunjucks.render('index.html', getContext()));
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e);
    }
  });
}

// ...
```

My tree:

```
index.html  // Compiled HTML.
src/
  index.html  // Template/Nunjucks HTML.
templates/
  somePartial.html
```

Then including:

```
{% include "./templates/somePartial.html" %}
```

Comment: @PiotrAdamMilewski check it out